# Rails and Mongoid on a Vagrant Box

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, vagrant

I have a vagrant box set up with rails 4, the latest version of mongodb and mongoid. Once the vagrant box is up I can hit mongodb using `mongo` and I can access mongodb and any existing databases. The problem seems to be that my rails code isn't writing into the mongodb. Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a configuration issue that I'm not seeing? What tests should I run so that I can get some errors to help debug this issue?

Thanks!

Edit: Okay so upon restarting the webserver it seems to work now. Or at least I can try to query mongodb via rails console. I'll update as I continue to test more.

Edit 2: And so in the rails sandboxed console I can try to look into a User collection using User.all but User.first gives me an error as follows.

```
Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionConfig:
Problem:
  No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'.
Summary:
  When attempting to create the new session, Mongoid could not find a session configuration for the name: 'default'. This is necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
Resolution:
  Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the sessions key that a configuration exists for 'default'. If you have set the configuration programatically, ensure that 'default' exists in the configuration hash.
```

Following the Resolution suggestions, I did a quick check of mongoid.yml under `config/mongoid.yml` and I see it listed as such

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: mongoid
      hosts:
        - localhost:21017
      options:
  options:
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: mongoid
      hosts:
        - localhost:21017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

Edit 3: It looks like this issue only occurs when I'm trying to run the rails console in sandbox mode. It works fine in the normal rails console. Anyway to make it work in the sandbox console?

Edit 4: spelling

Any insights will be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the configuration file. The third line:

```
defualt:
```

should be:

```
default:
```

Comment: ahhh yea...I fixed that...that's not the problem.

Comment: What happens now when you try to run User.all? Do you get an other error message?

Comment: What's the error you get for User.first? Also, I'm not sure you can run Mongoid in sandbox mode at all. MongoDB doesn't have transactions, so don't think it can rollback the changes you make in sandbox mode.

Comment: The error is as I had written above. I think I've done it before. I had actually done the rails tutorial by Hartl using mongoid. I've gone through the rails console in sandbox mode before. I don't remember it causing problems...but I really didn't have that great of a grasp of what was going on at that time so I could have been wrong.

Comment: When you call Rails.env in sandbox console, it outputs development?